# One solution to check every form if empty

Tags: php, forms

I wonder if there is a smart solution to check every form - independent which form it is - if it is empty or not.

Like some solution I can declare in top of my class file and it will grab all the text input filed.

What I wan't to accomplish is to not be needed to create a input check if it is empty or not in every function dependent on a input text field. Just one clean solution fitting for all input text fields.

Hope you grab my idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (array_reduce($_POST, function($res, $x) { return $res + strlen($x); }, 0) === 0)
  echo 'Form empty';
```

**Edit:**
An even simpler solution is

```
if (count(array_filter($_POST)) === 0)
  echo 'Form empty';
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no point in such an idea.
Beside of such a general checking you will have to check the fields individually.
So, you will check required fields anyway and there is no point in running additional loop.